# PowerShell - Get-ChildItem too slow while searching for files on a Network Share

Tags: powershell

Here is my code I have spent all week on, of course with the help of stackoverflow to search for files by name and it works except Get-ChildItem seems to be very slow while searching our network shared folder that has over 150k files.

Is there a better way to write this? Thank you in advanced.

```
$fileName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a File Name'

# Set the path to the folder you want to search
$folderPath = '\\networkshare'

if ($pdfFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*$fileName*.pdf" -File -Recurse )
{
    & {
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $pdfFile.Count; $i++)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                $('#' + (' ' * $pdfFile.Count.Length)) = $i + 1
                PDFName = '{0}' -f $pdfFile[$i].BaseName
                Created = '{0}' -f $pdfFile[$i].CreationTime
            }
        }
    } | Out-String -Stream
    $selection = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter PDF(s) to open') -split ',' | %'Trim'
    foreach ($selected in $selection)
    {
        $pdf = $pdfFile[$selected - 1]
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" $pdf.FullName
        Write-Host $pdf
        pause 10
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host -Object "No file with name `"$fileName`" found."
}
```

My code just asks the user to enter the file they are looking for (which are all PDF files only).
Example of what the code does.

```
Enter a File Name: 1234

Returns files simular to what the user entered

#  PDFName           Created
-- -------           -------
 1 TK1234            12/14/2022 6:19:45 AM 
 2 TK5467-5001234215 12/24/2022 10:57:36 AM
```

This works great testing this on my c:\temp folder but when I try our network share it takes a long time to get the results.

Comment: Scanning through 150k files is going to take a long time.  How about adding a cache?  Another approach would be installing the Everything app for Windows.  It can enumerate file shares, and has an SDK. You can use its SDK with PowerShell, which would give you very fast search results.  If you want to add a cache, I can help you with an example.

Comment: Why not just use what the Windows OS gives you and avoid scripting this at all? Just enable ***'File Service Resource Manager (FSRM)'*** file scans to run 24 by 7 and use the reports from it. ['File Service Resource Manager (FSRM)' 'file scan by date'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27File+Service+Resource+Manager+(FSRM)%27+%27file+scan+by+date%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: going to take a look at the Everything app,but it would be niceto give my script to a few employees vs installing another app.

Comment: what powershell version are you on? can you download modules?

Comment: PowerShell Version 7

Answer (score 1):

This can be faster using a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0) to traverse the directories instead of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2). As for the selection, [`Out-GridView -PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-pass-multiple-items-through-out-gridview) allows picking multiple items and is already built-in, don't see a need for the extra logic.

```bash
$filter = '*{0}*.pdf' -f (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a File Name')
$queue  = [Collections.Generic.Queue[IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()

$folderPath = '\\networkshare'
$queue.Enqueue((Get-Item $folderPath))

$result = while($queue.Count) {
    try {
        $target = $queue.Dequeue()
        foreach($item in $target.EnumerateDirectories()) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)
        }
        foreach($item in $target.EnumerateFiles($filter)) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Created      = $item.CreationTime
                Name         = $item.Name
                AbsolutePath = $item.FullName
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # ignore inaccessible / access denied folders
        # can add error handling here if needed else leave blank
    }
}

if($result) {
    $edgePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
    $result | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Enter PDF(s) to open' | ForEach-Object {
        Start-Process -FilePath $edgePath -ArgumentList "`"$($_.AbsolutePath)`""
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host ('No file with name "{0}" found.' -f $filter)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this ending up taking longer to run but the pop-up box with the ability to select multiple files is really nice. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @timothytech could you try the code again using a Queue instead (see edit)? that should be faster, certainly faster than `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: I just tried this code and now it doesn't find any files. Not sure, but I tested several file names but it seems the change broke the script. Sorry..

Comment: @timothytech my bad, had a few typos. sorry

Comment: Hi Santiago, the code works now but this actually takes longer to search through the network share folders. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows native commands without ifilter to search  a remote drive I get after 120 seconds an accurate count of 43 files for o*.pdf However if I use explorer...

It takes me about 7 seconds to find 659 x PDF with \server o*.pdf or instantly show null for 1234*.pdf then only 3 seconds to report 18 x 12*.pdf, I can scan by eye which one I want or quickly refine the search to include contents of PDF.

[image]

It is fast and dirty like a blunt knife, it would be better using an ifilter aware tool like AgentRansack

[image]

On reviewing @postanote comments. It looks like

> "File Server Resource Manager" can be configured and managed by using the File Server Resource Manager app ***or by using Windows PowerShell.***